# Differential Equation: $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = xy + y\sin x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm trying to solve this differential equation and believe I may have solved it using the "separable equations" method.

Here's my work:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = xy + y\sin x = y(x + \sin x),$$

$${\mathrm{d} y} \frac{1}{y} = {\mathrm{d} x} (x+\sin x),$$

$$\int {\mathrm{d} y} \frac{1}{y} = \int {\mathrm{d} x} (x+\sin x),$$

$$\ln y = x^2 - \cos x + C,$$

$$y = e^{x^2 - \cos x + C}.$$

Does this look right? And/or, does this "solve" the equation?

Comment: One minor correction: the antiderivative of $x$ is $\frac{1}{2}x^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of small errors... the integral of ${1 \over y}$ should be $\ln |y|$ and the integral of $x$ is ${x^2 \over 2} + C$. So your answer is
$$|y| = e^{{x^2 \over 2} - \cos x + C}$$
This is the same as 
$$y = \pm e^{C} e^{{x^2 \over 2} - \cos x }$$
But $\pm e^C$ can be any (nonzero) constant, so this is exactly the same as 
$$y = C\,e^{{x^2 \over 2} - \cos x }$$

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.  You made one mistake, $\int x=\frac{x^2}2$, not $x^2$.

The answer should be:

$$
y=Ce^{\frac{x^2}2-\cos x}
$$